# How AsyncStorage should be modified such that it should persist inputtext value after refresh as well?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, persistent-storage

My code takes input in textinput and saves in asynchStorage-works fine in that. I need some help in modifying my code such that after refresh the textinput should be filled with same text that the user entered using redux-persist. Here is my **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, Button, View, AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

export default class AsyncStorageExample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        myKey: null
    }
  }

  async getKey() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
      this.setState({myKey: value});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
  }

  async saveKey(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error saving data" + error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.formInput}
          placeholder="Enter key you want to save!"
          value={this.state.myKey}
          onChangeText={(value) => this.saveKey(value)}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AsyncStorageExample', () => AsyncStorageExample)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call getKey() in splash screen or ComponentDidMount() method of your View where you want to display textInput

Comment: That's what I am asking how to do that?

Comment: Is that any function to refresh textInput ? or when it will be refresh?